# How do i position these bar graphs to their left and right instead of listing one below the other?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {Java};
\draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
\draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (.1,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{.05cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {polite};
\draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
\draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (3.5,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{.05cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {outgoing};
\draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
\draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (4,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{.05cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {good manners};
\draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
\draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (3.5,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{.05cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {pursuer of rabbits};
\draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
\draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (4.8,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first thing to do is not use `\vspace`, which is a command used to insert explicit **v**ertical **space** (or put them in new paragraphs). But it is unclear how many you want side-by-side. Surely all five won't fit..?

Comment: Also, an empty line signifies a paragraph break, so even without the `\vspace` commands they would end up on above the other. If you wrote `Text text <empty line> more text`, would you expect `more text` to be on the same line as `Text text`? Same thing with `tikzpicture`s.

Answer (score 2):

Put them all in one `tikzpicture` and use `scope` to move them around to wherever you like. With a scale on  the `tikzpicture` (or `scope`) the sizes can be changed. For clarity I put all also the first in a scope and printed all shifts, even the 0cm.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm]
    \node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {Java};
    \draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
    \draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (.1,.5);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,yshift=0cm]
    \node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {polite};
    \draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
    \draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (3.5,.5);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=-2cm]
    \node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {outgoing};
    \draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
    \draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (4,.5);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,yshift=-2cm]
    \node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {good manners};
    \draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
    \draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (3.5,.5);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=-4cm]
    \node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {pursuer of rabbits};
    \draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
    \draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (4.8,.5);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With a scaling of `.6` and without those `\vspace`s you will get at least three side by side. Experimentation is key (in order to properly get all to one line).

[image: picture of tikzpictures]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {Java};
\draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
\draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (.1,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {polite};
\draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
\draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (3.5,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {outgoing};
\draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
\draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (4,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {good manners};
\draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
\draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (3.5,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {pursuer of rabbits};
\draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
\draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (4.8,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```